# React table sort

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Am trying  to sort the react table but am getting stuck with type errors in ----

1. `const rows = this.state.data.map( (rowData) => <Row {...rowData} />);` 
   ---TypeError:

   `this.state.data.map` is not a function
2. `let vehicle = [...this.state.data]; ------TypeError: this.state.data is not iterable`
3. `compareBy(key) {}` ----  TypeError: Cannot find name 'compareBy'

. below is my code. kindly, help me do sorting.

```
     export interface VehicleListProps {
        vehicle: VehicleState;

        listVehicles: (limit: number, skip: number) => void;
        addVehicle: (id: string) => void;
        deleteVehicle: (id: string, limit: number, skip: number) => void; }

    const Row = ({name, type , color }) => (   
      <div className="row">
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div>{type}</div>
        <div>{color}</div>

      </div> );

    const VehicleList: React.FC<VehicleListProps> = (props) => {

        constructor(props); {
          this.state = {
            data: vehicle

    };


         this.compareBy = compareBy.bind(this);
         this.sortBy = sortBy.bind(this);
        }

         compareBy(key) {
          return function (a, b) {
            if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
            if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
            return 0;
          };
        }

        sortBy(key) {
          let vehicle = [...this.state.data];
          vehicle.sort(this.compareBy(key));
          this.setState({data: vehicle});
        }

        const rows = this.state.data.map( (rowData) => <Row {...rowData} />);

        return (

            <div>  

              <div className="row gap-20 masonry pos-r">
                  <Table id="dataTable" className="table table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead className="thead-dark" >
                          <tr>
                              <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('name')}>Name</th>
                              <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('type')}>Type</th>                     
                              <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('color')}>Color</th>         
                              <th></th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>{
                          vehicle.page.collection.map((vehicle, idx) => {
                              return (
                                  <tr key={idx}>
                                      <td><a className="vehicleName" href={`/vehicles/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.name}</a></td>
                                      <td>{vehicle.type}</td>

                                      <td>{vehicle.color}</td>

                                  </tr>
                              )
                          })
                      }</tbody>

                  </Table>


                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        ); }
```

Comment: You got problem with `this.state.data` as the error says, its not an array, please make a producible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did not understood can you please help again?

Comment: I am stuck with one issue in React which is related to sorting of rows in React-Table. Can you give me some idea how can I sort elements in this case - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68359658/1649217